# Python 星描く

Tags: python

Pythonで亀を使って星を複数描きたいんですが､どうすればいいですか？
最低星3つは描きたいです。
学校の先生に繰り返しで描かせると言われたんですがどういうふうにプログラムを作ったらいいか分かりません｡
回答お願いします｡

Comment: どういうことについて知りたいのかをはっきりさせるため、知りたい問題をより具体的にしたり、追加の詳細を書き加えたりしてください。現状のままだと何についての質問なのかが分かりづらいです。

Comment: 現状1つの星を書くことはできる、ということで良いでしょうか？

Comment: こんな動画が参考になるかも。[Draw Stars with Python Turtle - Full Tutorial](https://youtu.be/uGkpXxOEQ0Q) あとこんな記事も。[Turtle Stars](https://holypython.com/python-turtle-tutorial/turtle-stars/)

Answer (score 4):

タートルグラフィックスを習っているけれど、カメがどう動くのか、何の役に立つのかがさっぱり分からない方に向けた回答です。

まず[turtle](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/turtle.html)は[`forward(distance)`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.forward)でdistanceの長さだけ前進して線を引きます。
そして[`right(angle)`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.right)でangleの度数だけ回れ右します。

例えばturtleを対象にして`turtle.forward(10)`と`turtle.right(90)`の2つのコードを実行すると、「カメさん、(ペンをおろしたまま)10歩進みなさい」「カメさん、90度右に回りなさい」と命令し、カメは命令された通りに動きます。
慣れてしまえば当たり前なのですが、何度やっても結果は変わらないことがポイントです。
カメはコードに忠実に動き(たまに5歩しか動かないなんてことはない)、誤字があると動かない(`turtte.foward(10)`のようにスペルを間違うとエラーになる)ことを学べます。

この2つの処理を`for`文で繰り返すとあらゆる一筆書きができます。
五芒星を書くなら下記のコードでできます。

```
import turtle
for _ in range(5):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(144)
```

`for`を使わない場合、カメに同じ命令を5回書かなければいけません。
こうして命令をコピペせずに繰り返し命令を楽に書くことで、ループ処理の利点を学べます。

あとは複数の星を書くために、角度や大きさを変えて星を書いたり、[`penup`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.penup)して移動した後に[`pendown`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.pendown)してから別の場所に星を書くことができます。
これで「カメが今どこにいるのか」「どの方角を向いてるのか」「ペンをおろしているのか」など、カメの状態を頭の中で整理することで、疑似的な`変数`を体験することができます。

今回は複数の星を描くため、`関数`を使って再帰処理をすることで長さの異なる五芒星を5つ描いてみます。
まだ関数を使ったことのない人が下記のサンプルコードを理解する必要はありません。

**サンプルコード**

```
import turtle

def draw_star(distance: int):
    for _ in range(5):
        turtle.forward(distance)
        turtle.right(144)
    if distance > 25:
        turtle.right(72)
        draw_star(distance / 2)

draw_star(400)
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.mainloop()
```

パソコンが得意で次のステップに興味のある人は、`draw_star`関数の第一引数`distance`に`400`を渡すことで`for`文で何が起こるのか考えてみましょう。
さらに関数内の`draw_star(distance / 2)`を呼び出すと、次に呼び出される`draw_star`関数の第一引数の値は何になり、`for`文で何が起こるのか、`if`文が実行されるのかを画面上のコードで考えてみてください。
(コードを印刷して、数値をシャーペンで書きながら処理の流れを追うことで`机上デバッグ`ができます。古来からあるアナログな手法ですが、学習の方法として有効です)
そして`draw_star(400)`や`if distance > 25:`その他のコードの値を変更して遊んでみましょう。

納得するまで遊んで再帰処理を理解できたなら、あなたはもうハッカーの一歩を踏み出しました。
あとはコードをアレンジして星の数を増やしたり、[`pencolor`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.pencolor)を変えてカラフルな図形を書いて友達や先生を驚かせちゃいましょう！

ちなみにサンプルコードが理解できなくても焦らなくて大丈夫です。
再帰処理はかなり難しい処理なので、社会人でも理解するのに苦労する人がけっこういます。
逆にすんなり理解できた人は素晴らしい！プログラムの素養が高いかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく、タートルグラフィックスのpython版のことだと思います。
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/turtle.html?highlight=%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9